# Strange error when using Rails with Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger

I get the following Passenger error:

```
undefined method `post_reset' for Gem:Module
```

Someone knows what this could mean? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the very same error after performing a `gem pristine --all` to get rid of the annoying deprecation messages introduced with the latest rubygems update.

After that my `mod_passenger.so` got deleted resulting in this (misleading) error message. Try restarting Apache, it won't be possible if you are having the same problem.

The solution was to once again execute `passenger-install-apache2-module`. After that I could restart Apache and the error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

i tried it myself and ended up with downgrading rubygems to 1.7.2, works again!